# Error passing parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I need to pass two values to a javascript function from inside another javascript function as follows:

```
Something.innerHTML = Something.innerHTML + "<input type = 'submit' name = 'bbb' value = 'aaa' onclick = funcName(" + var1 + "," + var2 + "); />";
```

where: `var1`, `var2` are two variables, whose values as shown by *firebug* are `2` and `3` respectively.

i) No error arises if I pass a single value, and the function receives a single value, i.e. `funcName(var1)`

ii) No error arises if I pass `var1` twice, i.e. `funcName(var1, var1);`

iii) Error as reported by *firebug* when I pass `var1, var2`, i.e. `funcName(var1, var2);` is: `missing ) after argument list` and reports the following line: `funcName(2,3`

**EDIT:** 
i) If I replace, 'var1', with any other variable, I am afraid the function does not work.

ii) I tried appending the two params using:

temp = var1 + "--" + var2;

And then 'decoding' it back in the receiving function, so that you could pass a 'single' parameter, but of no use.

Comment: This part seems correct, can you post more code?

Comment: @Viruzzo: Nothing extra: In the function definition part, I use: function funcName(a, b) { alert(a); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't put quotes around the attribute. Moreover you shouldn't use spaces:

```
onclick=\"funcName(" + var1 + "," + var2 + ");\"
```

Comment: @El Classico: What is the result if you inspect the element with Firebug? Are you sure they are numerical values and not something else?

Comment: Yes. Checked using firebug, and for other cases, even using alert();.

Comment: @El Classico: Does it pass if you use `var2` twice?

Comment: Nope. The error it shows is a bit different though: missing ) after argument list

score(1

Comment: @El Classico: What if you put the value of `var2` literally in the code instead of referring to it?

Comment: But the values that I obtain, i.e. var1, var2 are using an ajax post in the first function, which I need to pass to the second.

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick = funcName(" + var1 + "," + var2 + "); />"
```

should probably be

```
onclick='funcName(" + var1 + "," + var2 + ");' />"
        ^-- missing                          ^--missing
```

Comment: Had that beem an error, you would have errors for the other cases too.